# React Native Webview not loading on certain devices

Tags: android, webview, react-native

On our app we are using a Webview Component to display some information that is in our website, this is working as intended for most cases, however we have been told by a couple of users that the Webview never loads on their devices. I would like to know the reason for this weird behavior on the React Native Webview.

We have been reported that it doesn't work on

- Huawei Ascend
- Acer Liquid

Thank you very much for any information on this problem.

Comment: you would probably better ask in react native repository, here ppl expect to see some code